# iTunes Connect Opt-In Rate Over 100 Percent

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

Was looking at the default metrics within iTunes Connect today. Clicked on the question mark icon at the top of the page next to the **About App Analytics Data** title to see what the current Opt-In rate is and it says (emphasis added by me):

> We only show data from users who have agreed to share their diagnostics and usage information with app developers. In the last 30 days, **545%** of users that installed "The App" agreed to share their data.

How is that even possible?! And would the be skewing the analytics data?

I assume that if it says I have 100,000 Sessions but the Opt-In rate is 500%, that would mean that maybe I only actually have 20,000 Sessions...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for Apple support.

Comment: @rmaddy Understood, although I would say that could be said for almost any question on this site about a technology developed by another company.

Comment: Not exactly - SO main purpose is to help you with your **code**. Your problem isn't even remotely connected with programming.

Comment: @Losiowaty I will give you not directly connected but it is certainly remotely connected. Also that is not the reasoning given for closing this post. I see in the related questions tab, plenty of other iTunes Analytics questions that have not been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the *.greater.than.* 100% Opt-In rate is resolved in the current App Store Connect. For example, `29%`.

[image]